# How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen in Python 2?

Tags: python, popen

I would like to run a process from Python (2.4/2.5/2.6) using `Popen`, and I
would like to give it a string as its standard input.

I'll write an example where the process does a "head -n 1" its input.

The following works, but I would like to solve it in a nicer way, without using
`echo`:

```
>>> from subprocess import *
>>> p1 = Popen(["echo", "first line\nsecond line"], stdout=PIPE)
>>> Popen(["head", "-n", "1"], stdin=p1.stdout)
first line
```

I tried to use `StringIO`, but it does not work:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> Popen(["head", "-n", "1"], stdin=StringIO("first line\nsecond line"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 533, in __init__
    (p2cread, p2cwrite,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 830, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I guess I could make a temporary file and write the string there -- but that's not very nice either.

Comment: It's the same question, but this one is about Python 2, where the answer is a tiny bit different from Python 3 (you don't need the "b" in front of the input string and don't need to decode the result).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to feed your string to [communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) as a string?

```
Popen.communicate(input=my_input)
```

It works like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["head", "-n", "1"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('first\nsecond')
```

output:

```
first
```

I forgot to set stdin to subprocess.PIPE when I tried it at first.

Comment: +1 I was just part way through composing an answer suggesting the same thing.

Comment: ditto mikej :) I posted and just deleted

Answer (score 5):

Use [os.pipe](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pipe):

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> import os, sys
>>> read, write = os.pipe()
>>> p = Popen(["head", "-n", "1"], stdin=read, stdout=sys.stdout)
>>> byteswritten = os.write(write, "foo bar\n")
foo bar
>>>
```

Comment: +1, I suggested communicate but it didn't work. Your solution works.

Comment: I tried out your "communicate" solution, and it worked! Actually, I liked it better, and I just was to accept it when it got deleted. Could you put it back?

Comment: Note that this is limited to sending a maximum of 64kB at a time, as I just discovered.